# What is the purpose of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#

what is  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in c#  , actually unable to find the answer , why we use it , for what purpose , please explain in easy words
Please Explain in easy words ! Why we use this . On the other hand , if i donot use this , results are still same . So why what is the purpose of this ?

Comment: It's your operating system's current culture (or language, to simplify). So most of the time, it is implicitly used, and explicitly using it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `CultureInfo` as a collection of settings for a particular geographical region.

A `CultureInfo` object specifies how a piece of information is rendered for a particular culture. It contains settings for writing directions and other related settings, dates formatting, calender, currency etc.

With `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` the culture context for the current thread is given. This is used by functions like `ToString()` to define the string format of a DateTime value, when no explict culture is provided as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

CultureInfo contains information on how to deal with data representation in different countries.

As for example date format (in my country it's DD/MM/YYYY, in the US it's MM-DD-YYYY) or floating point number representation (3,14 vs 3.14).